# sql update / replace row leaving some columns unaffected

Tags: sql, sqlite, rdbms

I would like to perform an row update / replace so that columns for which values are not specified remain as they were e.g. for a 4 column table:

```
-- expecting row = 99|a|b|?
replace into game_data ( id, col_a, col_b ) values ( 99, "a",  "b" ); 

-- expecting row = 99|a|b2|c  < a remains unchanged
replace into game_data ( id, col_b, col_c ) values ( 99, "b2", "c" );
```

Is this possible? If not, I am guessing the alternative would be to extract the existing row, merge the data as required then perform the replace, but this seems like something a db should do?? a schema thing?

(for sqlite3 being used from bash script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the UPDATE statement, like this:

```
UPDATE game_data
  SET col_a = 'a', col_b = 'b'
WHERE id= 99
```

This will set values for col_a and col_b for the row with id of 99, leaving all other column values unchanged.

<strike>(NOTE:  REPLACE() is a string replacement function).</strike>

NOTE:  REPLACE means different things in different SQL dialects, unfortunately.

Comment: Considering that the query even works, it should be quite obvious that that `REPLACE` is not the string function. Read the docs: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html

Comment: Ah, right.  I'm mixing my SQL dialects.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: that does work the way i'd like, it will be a pain to construct the statement though. Ive come across another post for the same issue, the reply mentions a second statement being required and the syntax looks a little different. is a two part second statement required? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677066/sql-a-query-to-insert-new-record-or-replace-only-some-fields

Comment: the other thread has a post doing a table merge could I put my existing inserts ito a temporary table and then merge the two somehow?

Comment: For that other question, the two part SQL operation looks like (to me) it's there because of the way their update problem is set up.  You may or may not need to do that, depending on exactly what you're trying to do.